# JavaScript in asp.net core react redux project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, redux, visual-studio-2019

I have a asp.net core 3 react redux template based app.

I am using this app from a mobile app that knows how to inject javascript functions into the webview in order to interact between native C# code and the webview javascript code.

In order to do this I need a global method that the rest of the pages javascript can access that inside of it can then call the injected javascript from the mobile app.

Here is my global javascript. it is contained in a file called jsinteraction.js

```
export function invokeCSCode(data){
    if (invokeCSharpAction)
       invokeCSharpAction(data);
    else
       console.log('invokeCSharpAction not found');
}
```

the problem I am having is that when I run this web site and then connect to it from my mobile app I get what looks like an ESLint error and the whole page just shows that error. it says:

Failed to compile

> ./src/helpers/jsinteraction.js Line 3: 'invokeCSharpAction' is not
>   defined no-undef Line 4: 'invokeCSharpAction' is not defined no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

The invokeCSharpAction won't exist during compile building of the app, but will once the mobile app has injected its code.

I thought using if (invokeCSharpAction) would be able to handle runtime detection.

I have also tried code I found in searching for it like this:

```
if (typeof invokeCSharpAction === function)
```

but I get the same error.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the function from the window:

```
export function invokeCSCode(data){
if (window.invokeCSharpAction)
   window.invokeCSharpAction(data);
else
   console.log('invokeCSharpAction not found');
}
```

Comment: No problem! Now you know :)